# Why does rails log an empty line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging

If I format the log message in Rails, I often get an empty line. For example:

```
Started GET "/assets/jquery.ifixpng.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-06 12:59:43 +0100
2012-03-06 12:59:43 INFO Served asset /jquery.ifixpng.js - 200 OK (26ms)
2012-03-06 12:59:43 INFO

Started GET "/assets/logo.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-06 12:59:43 +0100
2012-03-06 12:59:43 INFO Served asset /logo.png - 200 OK (26ms)
2012-03-06 12:59:43 INFO
```

Custom format_message

```
class Logger
  def format_message(severity, timestamp, progname, msg)
    "#{timestamp.to_formatted_s(:db)} #{severity} #{msg}\n"
  end 
end
```

How do I get rid of the empty lines like 2012-03-06 12:59:43 INFO ?

I've already checked on msg.empty? or msg.nil? but without any success. I also checked on \n or \r or \n\n or \r\r ...

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with [this change](http://www.ubergeekunlimited.org/blog/2012/11/09/how-to-disable-annoying-asset-related-log-messages-in-rails/) ( [internet archive backup](https://web.archive.org/web/20150511194710/http://www.ubergeekunlimited.org/blog/2012/11/09/how-to-disable-annoying-asset-related-log-messages-in-rails) ) in an attempt to allow for silencing the asset log messages somewhat.